# How to iterate a key and value into a dictionary based off what is already in the dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to duplicate a dictionary multiple times based off of the subsamples value in dictionary test1.

```
test1={'Subsamples':3}
test2={'Substrate':0,'Incubation Time':0}
test3={'Colonies':0,'Color':0,'Size':0}

if test1['Subsamples']>0:
    for x in range(0,test1['Subsamples']):
        #Magic happens here

print (test1)
>>>{'Subsamples':3}
print (test2)
>>>{'Substrate1':0,'Incubation Time1':0,'Substrate2':0,'Incubation Time2':0,'Substrate3':0,'Incubation Time4':0}
print(test3) 
>>>{'Colonies1':0,'Color1':0,'Size1':0,'Colonies2':0,'Color2':0,'Size2':0,'Colonies3':0,'Color3':0,'Size3':0}
```

So in the example above the value for key Subsamples is three, so the dictionary is "copied" 3 times with the number added to the end of each key each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you want to do is:

```
def dict_mult(d, n): 
     assert n >= 0 
     ret = {} 
     for i in range(n): 
         for k, v in d.items(): 
             ret['%s%s' % (k, i+1)] = v 
     return ret
```

However, that looks like a strange thing to do... The dict you produce looks hard to handle by the rest of your program (having to build the keys with string concatenation).

Are you sure you should not rather produce something like

```
{('Colonies',1):0,('Color',1):0,('Size',1):0,('Colonies',2):0,('Color',2):0,('Size',2):0,('Colonies',3):0,('Color',3):0,('Size',3):0}
```

or even better

```
[
  {'Colonies':0,'Color':0,'Size':0},
  {'Colonies':0,'Color':0,'Size':0},
  {'Colonies':0,'Color':0,'Size':0},
]
```

?

The later being easily produce by 
`[dict(test3) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Ah yeah, the 
```
{('Colonies',1):0,('Color',1):0,('Size',1):0,('Colonies',2):0,('Color',2):0,('Size',2):0,('Colonies',3):0,('Color',3):0,('Size',3):0}
```
Is much better. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Yeah, the first alternative you proposed looks far better. I'm trying to implement it but am having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: just replace `"%s%s" % (k, i+1)` with `(k, i+1)` in the function `dict_mult` in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `my_dict.items()` to iterate over keys and values as the same time.

Here is one way to answer :

```py
test1 = {'Subsamples': 3}
test2 = {'Substrate': 0, 'Incubation Time': 0}
test3 = {'Colonies': 0, 'Color': 0, 'Size': 0}

def create_new_dict(dict_number, dict_to_apply):
    new_dict = {}
    size = dict_number['Subsamples']
    if size > 0:
        for x in range(0, size):
            for key, value in dict_to_apply.items():
                new_dict[key + str(x+1)] = value
    return new_dict


print(create_new_dict(test1, test2))
# {'Substrate1': 0, 'Incubation Time1': 0, 'Substrate2': 0, 'Incubation Time2': 0, 'Substrate3': 0, 'Incubation Time3': 0}
print(create_new_dict(test1, test3))
# {'Colonies1': 0, 'Color1': 0, 'Size1': 0, 'Colonies2': 0, 'Color2': 0, 'Size2': 0, 'Colonies3': 0, 'Color3': 0, 'Size3': 0}
```